# Discussion forum with collapsed forums at start

Tags: forum

We use the discussion forum in EE 6.3.4. On Forum Home all forums are open at startup, i.e. not collapsed. You can close the forums yourself with the - sign on the right. The state of the different forums is stored in cookies.

Is there a way to set all forums to be collapsed at startup? I can't find any configuration option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe this is supported out of the box.  That being said I'm sure you could manually do it if need be.

Comment: Okay. Sure, manually we can.